# How to group by particular year using condition in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to count particular year count using mongoose group by and aggregate function, but i am not using condition to group particular year,i have to use below code,

```
Opp.aggregate([
    {$project:{
    _id: {year: {$year: '$HireDate'}},
    hireDateValue: {year: {$year: '$HireDate'}},
    hireDateCount: {$cond: [{"$and":[{"$or":[{"$eq":["$HireDate","1994-01-17 00:00:00.000"]}]}]}, 1, 0]}
    }},
    {$group: { _id: '$hireDateValue', count: {$sum: '$hireDateCount'} }},
    {$sort: {_id: 1}}
    ], function (err, dateResult) {
    resultAggr[0].items = dateResult;
    res.send([resultAggr]);
    });
```

My response,

```
[

    [
        {
            "id":7,
            "_id":"HiredDate",
            "items":[
                {...},
                {
                    "_id":{
                        "year":1990
                    },
                    "count":0
                },
                {
                    "_id":{
                        "year":1991
                    },
                    "count":0
                },
                {
                    "_id":{
                        "year":1992
                    },
                    "count":0
                },
                {
                    "_id":{
                        "year":1993
                    },
                    "count":0
                },
                {
                    "_id":{
                        "year":1994
                    },
                    "count":0
                },{...}
            ],
            "expanded":true
        }
    ]

]
```

pls help how to use condition when grouping particular year,

Comment: please give some solution to solve this problem

Comment: User this one on hireDateCount => { $cond: { if: { $eq: ["$HireDate","1994-01-17 00:00:00.000"] }, then: 1, else: 0 } }

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with `hireDateCount` ?

Your query is trying to calculate the total of HireDate where HireDate is "1994-01-17 00:00:00.000" and group by year

If you want to compute the number of hire, group by year then this

```
Opp.aggregate([
    {$project:{
        _id: {year: {$year: '$HireDate'}},
        hireDateValue: {year: {$year: '$HireDate'}}
    }},
    {$group: { _id: '$hireDateValue', count: {$sum: 1 } }},
    {$sort: {_id: 1}}
    ], function (err, dateResult) {
       resultAggr[0].items = dateResult;
       res.send([resultAggr]);
});
```

Or number of hire in 2015 (filter HiredDate to lower than 2016 and greater or equal 2015)

```
Opp.aggregate([
    { $match: { HiredDate: { $lt: new Date("2016-01-01"), $gte: new Date("2015-01-01") } } },
    {$project:{
        _id: {year: {$year: '$HireDate'}},
        hireDateValue: {year: {$year: '$HireDate'}}
    }},
    {$group: { _id: '$hireDateValue', count: {$sum: 1 } }},
    {$sort: {_id: 1}}
    ], function (err, dateResult) {
       resultAggr[0].items = dateResult;
       res.send([resultAggr]);
});
```

Hope that helps